# second admob not showing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob

I added another admob to the APK and directly copied and pasted the same ad code. but the second test does not show the ad. Where do you think is the problem?

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
   </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

   
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

Answer (score 0):

your add id are same so change these id's.

your current id is this
android:id="@+id/adView"

Comment: Unfortunately same when i change id